# Android WebView LongPress does not fire when using Built in Zoom Controls?

Tags: android, android-webview

Does anyone know why the WebView onLongClick method doesnt fire event when the built in zoom controls are used, webView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true).

API level 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the zoom controls in your xml file